# not getting proper values according to x and y axis quadrants after joystick movement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi i am including this [react-joystick-component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-joystick-component) in my project to control the robots. when i move the joystick around i get values like (
eventDirection: "RIGHT"
eventType: "move"
eventX: 50
eventY: 50 ).

but for the minus values i get plus values only ( Y axis bottom right movement).

expecting values like the below images explained quadrants
[Quadrants](http://aventalearning.com/content168staging/Foundations/Foundations_2008CRAlgebra1A/unit4/section1.html)

help me to resolve this am new to ReactJS.

Code Samples

```
import { Joystick } from 'react-joystick-component';
class ManualControl extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    header.token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.state = {
        eventX: null,
        eventY: null,
        eventType: null,
        eventDirection: null,
        eventTime: null
    };
}

handleMove = (event) => {
     console.log('handle move' + event.direction);
     console.log('handle move' + event.x);
     console.log('handle move' + event.y);
     console.log('handle move' + event.type);
}

handleStop = (event) => {
    console.log('handle stop');
}

render()  {
  return (
  <Joystick size={100} baseColor="#b7b7b7" stickColor="#ccc" move= 
  {this.handleMove} stop={this.handleStop}></Joystick>
  )

}
}
```

thank you

Comment: Can you provide some code samples? Specifically the code used to handle the joystick input events.

Comment: code sample added, i have imported react component and extended class name in my code. @sme

Comment: When moving to the bottom-right, what is the value of `event.direction`? If it provides data indicating both 'BOTTOM' and 'RIGHT', then you may just have to check if one of the directions is 'BOTTOM' or 'LEFT', then multiply the respective x or y value by -1.

Comment: yes, but that control gives only one direction when we move down 'BOTTOM' and 'RIGHT' after moving in diagonal ( towards down-right ). any other package which support these action at a time.. @sme

Comment: Is the event called multiple times then? IE, if you move diagonally to the bottom-right, is the event called at least once for 'BOTTOM' and at least once for 'RIGHT'?

Comment: yes it calls at-least once. for every call the state will be updated by the Handler @sme

Comment: found an alternate package where it provides an solution with required data values to control the robots 
link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-nipple

Comment: Thats good. Funny name for the package too...